# Finding conditional expected value $E[y|x]$

Tags: probability

joint pdf : $ f(x,y) = 3y^2/x^3$ from $0<y<x<1$

I needed marginal probability f(X) which I found to be 1 since I integrated $3y^2/x^3$ from $0$ to $X$

The conditional probability of y given x is then the same as the joint pdf.

So $E[y|x] = \int{x3y^2/x^3dx}$ from $0$ to $1$.

But then my answer is in terms of y while I know it should be a function in terms of X. Where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Simply integrate the $y$-term from $0$ to $1$.

$$\mathbb{E}[Y \mid X] = \int_{0}^{1}yf_{Y \mid X}(y \mid x)\text{ d}y = \int_{0}^{1}y\left(\dfrac{3y^2}{x^3}\right)\text{ d}y = \dfrac{3}{x^3}\int_{0}^{1}y^3\text{ d}y\text{.}$$